# Uncaught AssertionError: expected 404 to equal 405

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to test a server I have running. What I need to do is perform mocha testing on the response that the server gives. I am very new to this, so please forgive any errors that have been made.

Test is supposed to be passing, however it is not. I am very new to this, so I have not tried any alternative solutions. Thank you.

In Index.js I have:

```
console.log('index.js executing!');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
res.send('Hello, World!');
});

app.get('/', function(req,res){
res.send('status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED');
});

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port,function() {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

And I am testing it with mocha :

```
console.log('test/test.js executing');

const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const request = require('superagent');
const status = require('http-status');

const apiRoot = 'http://localhost:3000/';

describe('hello API', function(){
it('GET request returns text "Hello, World!".',function(done){
request.get(apiRoot)
    .end(function(err,res){
      expect(err).to.not.be.an('error');
      expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(status.OK);
      expect(res.text).to.equal('Hello, World!');
   done();
   });
});


it('POST request is not allowed',function(done){
 request.post(apiRoot)
   .end(function(err,res){
     expect(err).to.be.an('error');
     expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
  done();
  });
 });
});
```

The test is expected to pass.

The actual result that I am getting is:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: expected 404 to equal 405
      + expected - actual

      -404
      +405

      at /home/plc/cs2410/test/test.js:26:27
      at Request.callback (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:826:3)
      at IncomingMessage.parser (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:1036:18)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
```

Lines 26 and 27 are:

```
expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
done();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a 404 because your Express server is not listening for a `POST` to that endpoint. If you look, you've defined two `GET`s for that endpoint. You're also responding to the second request with a string that says `status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED`, not an actual 405 status code. You need to change your second `app.get` to something like this:

```
app.post('/', function(req,res){
  res.send(405, 'Method Not Allowed');
});
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. Thank you very much ! :)